# scope of variables when using for-loop in java - eclipse / compiler error?

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, scope

I've written the following code:

```
for(int layer = 0; layer <countLayers; layer++);
{
    List<Sprite> spritesInLayer = sceneGraph.getLayer(layer);
}
```

when i compile this snippet, I get an error, that in the line within the for-Loop, eclipse complains that 'layer' is an unknown symbol [... = sceneGraph.getLayer(layer);] and wants me to introduce the field / variable / ... 'layer'.

But when using this snippet, it works.

```
int layer = 0;
for(layer = 0; layer <countLayers; layer++);
{
    List<Sprite> spritesInLayer = sceneGraph.getLayer(layer);
}
```

does anybody know, what I'm missing in the first code? Or might this be some kind of a bug of eclipse / the java compiler?

I'm using Java 6 JDK Update 20 64 bit on Win 7 64-bit Home Premium and Eclipse Helios 64-bit (build 20100617-1415)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
for(int layer = 0; layer <countLayers; layer++);
```

to

```
for(int layer = 0; layer <countLayers; layer++)
```

The spurious semicolon means that the for loop has an empty body.  The following `{....}` is interpreted as a separate statement.  And of course, `layer` is out of scope within that block.

Comment: *duh*

I didn't see this - when working on my laptop, I press sometimes accidentially on the touchpad and overwrite some lines, or insert code at the wrong position - this is how that semicolon came in there (at least I think so, as there are some lines missing, which should be below the for-Loop)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

delete the semicolon after the `for` line!
The contents of the braces are not looped in your example, and therefore `layer` is undefined...

That's why eclipse is useful!

Answer (score 1):

Please remove semicolon ";" from following line.

for(int layer = 0; layer < countLayers; layer++);

for statement doesn't require ;